# Testing similar applications with only one selenium Project

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, ui-automation

I am currently building a Selenium project which will be used for functional testing for 3 applications. These 3 applications have most of their functionality in common, and their differences are mostly look and feel.

I have already advanced a great deal into the project, but the problem is that it was considered originally to be used for only one of the 3. I am trying to be able to adapt this Project to test all 3 applications, I reckon that some changes will have to take place in order for that to happen, as for example whereas some application may call a certain button "add to cart" while another may call it "add to bag" (this is some hypothetical example) and whenever the applications differ I add a check that says: if I am in application 1 do this, else if you are testing application 2 do this other thing, else if its 3 being tested, then do this other thing.

I have recently tried to use spring to do some dependency injection through the @Value tag, that did not work.

I would like to hear any ideas that would help me solve this problem in an elegant way, without having to do much code changes.

Any solution that would not require to change the existing functions signatures would be ideal.

Comment: Are you using PageFactory for all your controls?

Comment: Yes, I am using the page Factory Pattern @SiKing

Comment: So you should be able to make changes in just the Page Object classes to handle all the different apps.